# "No route matches [GET] after passenger upgrade from 4 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have upgraded from passenger 4.0.59 to 5.0.18 and now my application is down with rails error. I was able to do passenger upgrade successfully on an another application without any issues with same configurations as below.

- Rails version: 4.2.4
- Ruby version: 2.2.3
- Passenger version: 5.0.18

> {"timestamp":"2015-12     29T08:37:34Z","severity":"FATAL","type":"exception","message":"No route matches [GET] \"/go-app/systemcheck\": vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'","exception_id":"96be9f1869738d976

I have checked passenger.conf and sites-enabled/go-app.conf, everything looks fine and pointing to write path as compared to the another application that worked just fine.

Has anyone faced such issues? I don't understand why it's working one app and not on another.

Comment: I think you have updated passenger in ruby 2.2.3, current is still pointing to 2.2.0. Try setting current and default ruby to 2.2.3, see if your passenger is configured and updated there.